# Bluebird (or other Promise library) Keep Promise Error Stack Traces

Tags: javascript, stack, promise, try-catch, bluebird

Okay, I may be just missing the obvious, but I can't seem to find the general answer to this, and my Google-Fu has so far failed me.

In a Catch handler of a Promise, how do you re-throw the error, while still keeping the Promise stack trace of the original error?

That perhaps is not the correct description, so here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/8sgj8x4L/19/

With this code, the traced stack is:

```
Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String]
    at RejectWithAnError (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:51:19)
    at https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:57:14
From previous event:
    at StartTheProgram (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:56:6)
    at window.onload (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:67:1)
bluebird.js:1444 Unhandled rejection an error occurred
```

However, if a catch handler is added, and the error is re-rejected or re-thrown from that handler, then the stack becomes the location of the new Reject method call:

https://jsfiddle.net/8sgj8x4L/18/

Which traces this stack trace:

```
Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object String]
    at https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:65:23
From previous event:
    at StartTheProgram (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:61:11)
    at window.onload (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:70:1)
bluebird.js:1444 Unhandled rejection an error occurred
```

You can see the inner method which dispatched the original error, "RejectWithAnError", disappears from the second stack, as the error was caught and re-thrown.

For reference, here is the complete code from the JSFiddle (The newest Bluebird is referenced as an external dependency):

```
window.P.longStackTraces();

function RejectWithAnError() {
        var err = {error: true, message: "an error occurred"};
        err.prototype = new Error();
        return window.P.reject(err);
}

function StartTheProgram() {
    return RejectWithAnError()

    // Comment out this catch handler completely, and the Promise stack trace will correctly show the "RejectWithAnError" method as the error origin.
    .catch(function (status) {
            console.log("[WARN] Catch handler was called.");
            // Neither of these lines will show "RejectWithAnError" in the Promise chain stack trace.
            // throw status;
            return window.P.reject(status);

    });
}

StartTheProgram()
```

(On a side note, this is my first Stack Overflow question, so I hope this is the right format for this question.)

**Edit:** Updated example to reject using an object instance that inherits from a new `Error` instance.

Comment: Sidenote: Always reject with an instance of the `Error` constructor.

Comment: `status` is a string and can't hold stack information. That's why you should always use `Error` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I've updated the JSFiddle to use an Error instance: [https://jsfiddle.net/8sgj8x4L/12/](https://jsfiddle.net/8sgj8x4L/12/)  
The original stack trace is definitely helpful, ideally it would be to keep the promise chain that led up to the error via complex promise chains.  For instance, when enabling long-stack-traces in Bluebird, you can see all of the promises that led up to a failure, but if I add a catch handler, it seems to lose any information before that catch handler was called in the Promise chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors in JavaScript capture their trace *when they are created* so whenever you rethrow the error it will automatically capture the stack trace.

You are however not throwing errors. For this reason bluebird is giving you a warning (yay us). If you insist on throwing non-errors rather than properly subclassing errors - you'll need to manually trick the object to have a proper stack trace by manually capturing it. Either by creating a `new Error` inside the constructor and setting the `.stack` to its stack (might have to do some parsing) or by calling a specific method:

```
function RejectWithAnError() {
    var err = {error: true, message: "an error occurred"};
    // err.__proto__ = new Error(); -- this is how you'd do it with prototypes btw
    // explicitly capture the stack trace of the object
    if(Error.captureStackTrace) Error.captureStackTrace(err);
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6y4pL4h2/). Just a note, `.prototype` is a property *used by functions* to indicate *the prototype of objects created by calling the function as a constructor*. In order to set the prototype of an object directly you'd call `__proto__` although that's rarely a particularly good idea. Here's an example with [`__proto__` instead of Error.captureStackTrace](https://jsfiddle.net/h18mzo3z/).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think an important take-away for me from your input is that I am looking at the problem from the wrong perspective.  If I want to see the complete debug stack trace printed by Bluebird, back to the original location of the first Reject which started the current reject chain, it is probably problematic;  (Actually this seems almost like something that Bluebird would have to provide, an equivalent to `Error.captureStackTrace(err);`, but for the async call stack, e.g. a method named something like `Bluebird.captureAsyncStackTrace(err);`)

Comment: (Continued from previous comment, too many characters to fit in to a single comment it seems.) However, if the object supplied to the reject call is always an instance of an `Error`, then the original file location which dispatched the error can be known in any `catch` handler after that point in the Promise chain, and once that location is known, then it probably is not very important if the uncaught exception trace printed by Bluebird is complete.

Again, thanks very much for the input, it is definitely helpful.

Comment: +1, but could you please demonstrate the use of `Object.setPrototypeOf` instead of the deprecated `__proto__`?

Comment: It's not deprecated - it's standard @Bergi

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It's both - deprecated by `setPrototypeOf`, and standardised for (backwards) compatibility (check the annex B intro). I consider it obsolete - it should not appear in new code.

Answer (score -1):

```
Promise.config({
    warnings: false
});
```